# How can i create slider in UIViewController

Tags: iphone

How can i make `controller1` slide up and down by creating `slider` in it

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {


switch (buttonIndex) {

    case 0:{

        //Devanagari view display 

        ButtonViewController *controller1 = [[ButtonViewController alloc]init];

        controller1.delegate = self;

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                        initWithRootViewController:controller1];
        navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:2.0/12 saturation:2.0 brightness:4.0/10 alpha:1.0];

        [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

        [navigationController release];

        break;
    }
```

I got this from `User Experience Coding How-To's from Apple Reference` for creating `slider`

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
slider.continuous = YES;
slider.value = 25.0;
```

I added this whole thing right below `UIText View` in `controller1` but `controller1` is not sliding up and down.

Appreciate help.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you want to update a view's origin based on the value of the slider? If so you shouldn't be using `presentModalViewController` as that does an full transition to/from views, not a gradual moving.

Comment: In my viewcontroller i have lot of text might be of around 2 or 3 pages. I want to add the slider so that user can slide the view up and down to read it.

Comment: Why not put the text in a UITextView instead? It will allow the user to scroll text without modifying view geometry.

Comment: It is in uitextview and first i tried with scrollbar but not able to bring scrollbar [self.textView flashScrollIndicators];
    
    //[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([self.textView.text length], 0)];
    
    //self.textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    
    self.textView.editable = NO;

    //self.textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    
    //self.textView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    
    //self.textView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES; then thought might be good idea to have slider than scrollbar

Comment: actually i m missing slideraction method what will go in the slider action

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell about what you are trying to do, I think you should be using a UIScrollView and taking control of its contentOffset property. I threw together a quick example app, hopefully its what you are trying to do.

http://cl.ly/2Z3D1D0W1m332y313v0A